# Restricted Boltzmann Machine - preprocessing data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, rbm

I am programming on MATLAB and want to use RBMs with real-valued input, like greyscale images, so I tried to follow what Hinton said in [this article](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/esann-deep-final.pdf).

The images have integer values in [0, 255] and are stored in a matrix D which is [numImages x numPixel]. So I started preprocessing the data:

- scaled the entire dataset so that all the values are in [0, 1] with

  ```
  D = D / 255;
  ```
- brought every pixel to have zero mean across all images, so I subtracted from every column of the matrix its mean value with

  ```
  imgMean = mean(D);    % row vector
  D = D - repmat(imgMean, rows, 1);
  ```
- divided the entire dataset by its standard deviation, so that every pixel has unit variance, with

  ```
  D = D / std(D(:));
  ```

But when I try to plot the images, the result is clearly very dark, since many values become negative and are clipped to zero.

Is this ok or did I make any mistake with the preprocessing?

Comment: How are you plotting the images?

Comment: I am using the code provided by Hinton himself. Probably the interesting part about plotting is `imagesc(img2,[0 1]);` where img2 is what I want to plot, which is built as a "collage" of images from the test set and their reconstructions.

Comment: Does changing `imagesc` to `imshow` help?

Comment: Unfortunately no... The result is pretty much the same